# [console in rails]. uninitialized constant Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

when i run a method in terminal of rails. 
first time, it working :

```
 Spree::Campaign.first
 Campaign Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `campaigns`.* FROM `campaigns`   ORDER BY `campaigns`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Campaign id: 1, name: "campaign 1", user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-10-27 06:48:01", updated_at: "2015-10-29 04:22:03", description: nil, active: true>
```

but when i try run code above again

```
Spree::Campaign.first
NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::Campaign
from (irb):2
from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
from /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
from /home/kop/rails/donghoxteen/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/kop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/kop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Why? and how to fix this error??

Comment: Are you running `Spree::Campaign.first` in your rails console from your project directory? And it works first time and does not work the second time?

Comment: yes. how to fix errror?

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are getting seem to be intermittent. In your question text, the error is `uninitialized constant Spree::Campaign`, whereas in your question title, the error is `uninitialized constant Class`.

This points to there being something fundamentally wrong with your Ruby installation. `Class` is a core Ruby class, and the `Class` constant should always be there. It's hard to diagnose with just the information you have given, but it appears that constant lookup is broken in your Ruby installation.

I recommend re-installing Ruby.